# Clojure regex delete whitespace in (?<=) pattern

Tags: regex, clojure

I want to pick sentence from special prefix:

```
(re-find (re-pattern (str "(?<=" "\\+" "+:=)" ".+")) "++:= test test")
=> " test test"
```

I try to delete whitespace in the head of `test test`. So I change it to:

```
(re-find (re-pattern (str "(?<=" "\\+" "+:=\\s*)" ".+")) "++:= test test")
=>nil
```

but this code works:

```
(re-find (re-pattern (str "(?<=" "\\+" "+:=\\s)" ".+")) "++:= test test")
=> "test test"
```

Actually, there are not only one whitespace(maybe none too) before `test test`, I don't know why `\\s` work well but `\\s*` don't.

What happen in this code? How could I fix it?

Comment: Why do you break up the regex into partial string parts, why not just a single string ?

Comment: You can use the built in regex syntax: `#"(?<=\++:=\s).+"`. This creates a `java.util.regex.Pattern`, so it's the same as calling `re-pattern`.

Comment: I break up the regex into partial string because the middle keywords might change in future, "\\+" could be "-" or other unique symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***edit:*** If you have a lucky engine that does variable width lookbehinds
you can force it to work by sticking in a negative lookahead
using `(?<=\++:=\s*)(?!\s).+`

---

For other engines:

`\s*` can match a variable number of whitespace.
And `\++` can match a variable number of plus signs.

In all but the Dot-Net regex engine, *DON'T* allow variable width's in lookbehind assertions.

So this `(?<=\++:=\s*)` will throw an error, i.e. won't compile.

I'm not sure what you mean by *`don't work`* ...

---

The normal way around this is to capture what you need, then reference that.
`\++:=\s*(.+)`

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 14 ) 
++:= test test  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 5 , len 9 ) 
test test
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know loosbehind assertions don't allow variable. I thought it should fine, that is why I said `don't work`.